# How to setup the logging of my application with built with Flask and run with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, python-logging

I have created a simple application that returns a json object on demand based on a GET request. I have used the [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/) framework, and then I run in production with [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/).

It is not clear to me how to setup the logging so that my application integrates better with the other two libraries. To be precise, when I run my application I get this type of logging messages:

```
> gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 mymodule.api:app
[2023-11-28 17:29:27 +0100] [124978] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-11-28 17:29:27 +0100] [124978] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (124978)
[2023-11-28 17:29:27 +0100] [124978] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-11-28 17:29:27 +0100] [124979] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 124979
INFO:mymodule.api:Test
```

I'm using just the `app.logger`, as recommended in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/logging/).

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
app = Flask(__name__)
logger = app.logger
logger.info('Test')
```

The `mymodule.api` logger itself has no handler attached, and its parent is the `root` logger. How can I make the logging from my application to integrate better (at least to have the same formatter) with the ones from gunicorn?

More generally, it's not clear to me how to set it up in a seamless way. I can control the logging in gunicorn from command line arguments. But I'm not sure how to *propagate* this information to my own application. Currently I'm setting the level of `app.logger` by hard coding it in the program, for instance. Which is crude and very little flexible.

Comment: There's a decent overview of logging here... https://pymotw.com/3/logging/index.html

Comment: I know how to use the logging library. I have used for my own applications. My doubt concerns how to integrate better my own logging with the one setup for the other components my application relies on.